# Display/Render image in razor view asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to display image in the razor view which is strongly typed. I have Image Location stored in DB. I can see the location of image with

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImageLocation)
```

But i want to display the image.

I have the full path of the image file stored in DB. How to display image in the view now?

Comment: What's the type of `model.ImageLocation`?

Comment: It holds the absolute location of the image file stored in the disk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display image from location stored in Database asp.net mvc 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807569/display-image-from-location-stored-in-database-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
 @Html.Image(model => model.ImageLocation)
```

Comment: is there Html helper as `@Html.Image` ?

Comment: Looks like it's in [Futures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509352/where-is-html-image-in-asp-net-mvc-rc).

Comment: if you are not able to find the helper, you can use the html control and bind model as follow: 
<img src="@model.ImageLocation" />